# How do i decide what batteries i need for my robot?

Tags: mobile-robot, battery, power, hexapod

I am trying to design a quadrupod(hexapod without the middle legs) and I need to decide an appropriate battery source. Currently I have 8 Mg996r's and 4 SG90's. What i did to measure the battery voltage was that I connected a power source with a known voltage and connected a single black servo to a breadboard with a multimeter in series to measure the current the servo draws (in idle state and at a moving state), that way through Ohms law i could get the resistance within the Servo. I was told however this wouldn't work due to the complex control systems within the servos... How would I go about then deciding a power source for my robot?

Comment: you can try this video about [robot power](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iye4uVLmj8o&list=PLunhqkrRNRhYAffV8JDiFOatQXuU-NnxT&index=5) and has explained everything in detail.

Comment: @nitish Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Most parts have datasheets that list their current requirements. For the MG996R I found 500 to 900 milliamps. The SG90 lists 100 to 250 Milliamps. total draw for all will be between 2.4 amps to 8.2 amps. You probably will not need full current, but will most likely need above the minimum There will also be various power requirements for other equipment, lets say 5 amps total. If you want to run for 15 minutes you need a battery with an amp hour rating of 1.25 Amp Hours

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion that the power rating should be 1.25 Amp/hour?

Comment: @AbhinavRao think about how 1.25 relates to 5 ... how many hours is 15 minutes?

Comment: @jsotola so you calculated power for each component and added that?

Comment: Amp Hours is literally amps multiplied by hours